# If a csrf token is placed inside a hidden input, isn't it possible for a malicious website to use CURL

Tags: php

and then strip the tag from the source code to use on a malicious POST request?

Say for example, the website places a hidden input like so:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{session token here}" name="token">
```

And then the legit website will check the code:

```
<?php 
  if(Request::post('token') != Session::get('token'):
     //generate new token, display errors etc
  endif;
?>
```

Couldn't the illegitimate website use CURL to scrape the source code and get form by names/ids etc and then get that token and place it inside their forged form and bypass the token security?

Comment: Yes, they could. That's what targetted screen scrapers do. However that has nothing to do with CSRF - which is about drive-by request forgeries from browsers.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to move this myself, but for the record, this question may be better put on security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSRF ("cross-site request forgery") protection token must only be valid for a specific account (or, better yet, a specific session). An attacker who wanted to discover a victim's CSRF protection using `curl` or similar would need to know the victim's session token. *(Of course, if they have the session token, they can just make requests directly without bothering to send them across sites.)*

CSRF is an attack where I forge requests *in a user's session* by using my site to tell the user's browser to send a request to your site (which is hosted on a totally different server and domain name, of course, thus "cross-site"). It works, even though I (the attacker) don't know the victim's session token, because the victim's browser automatically sends all the cookies (for your site) with any request to your site, even if the request was made because of the content of *my* site.

I never see those cookies, though; they go straight from the victim's browser to your server, leaving mine totally out of the loop. I can't get them using JavaScript or similar, either, because of the same-origin policy. Since I don't have the session cookie, I can't add it to `curl`. Without that, I can't request the CSRF protection token *that is valid for the victim's session*, so if your server uses CSRF protection correctly, it won't trust the forged requests.